# Where can I find the source code for the program called useradd?

Tags: linux, opensuse, source-code, sled

I am running SLED 11, and I want to understand what the `useradd` command does and how it does what it does.  I know that SLED 11 is built from OpenSuSE 11.1 and I would be more than satisfied with the OpenSuSE 11.1 source code for `useradd`.

Where can I find the source code for `useradd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On openSUSE `useradd` is from package `pwdutils`. Homepage http://www.thkukuk.de/pam/pwdutils/, source ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/net/NIS/

Answer (score 3):

since SUSE is an rpm based distro, you should be able get it by:

```
$ rpm -qf `which useradd`
```

which will tell you which package it is in.  You can then go get that package source from the repository, which in my case is here: http://download1.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/releases/11/Fedora/source/SRPMS/shadow-utils-4.1.2-13.fc11.src.rpm (I run fedora; your package repository location will be different)

Answer (score 0):

The `useradd` utility might well be a script.

Try

```
$ file $(which useradd)
```

(or

```
file `which useradd`
```

if your shell doesn't support `$()` style command expansion).

If it is a script, use `more` or an editor...

Comment: file $(which useradd) returns: /usr/sbin/useradd: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386. version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.4, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about SLED, but the Debian version is available [here](http://pkg-shadow.alioth.debian.org/).